# How can I make my data od database Sqlitepersistant after reinstall android app

Tags: sqlite

after reinstall my app in Emulator I don't find my data in database Sqlite, so what can I do (NB: I fill database from a file .txt).
this is some code of Class that extends from SqliteOpenHelper

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CATEGORIE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CATEGORIE + " ("
        + COL_ID_CATEGORIE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_INTITULE + " TEXT NOT NULL);";


private static final String CREATE_TABLE_BLAGUE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BLAGUE + " ("
        + COL_ID_BLAGUE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_TITRE_BLAGUE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COL_DESC_BLAGUE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "+ COL_FAVORIS+" INTEGER DEFAULT 0, "
        +COL_ID_CATEGBLAGUE+" INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (" 
        + COL_ID_CATEGBLAGUE+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_CATEGORIE+"("+COL_ID_CATEGORIE+"));";





public DbBlague(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,int version) {

    super(context, name, factory, version);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CATEGORIE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_BLAGUE);


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```